Using AsyncStream vs @Observable macro in SwiftUI
I want to understand the utility of using AsyncStream when iOS 17 introduced @Observable macro where we can directly observe changes in the value of any variable in the model(& observation tracking can happen even outside SwiftUI view). So if I am observing a continuous stream of values, such as download progress of a file using AsyncStream in a SwiftUI view, the same can be observed in the same SwiftUI view using onChange(of:initial) of download progress (stored as a property in model object). I am looking for benefits, drawbacks, & limitations of both approaches.
Specifically, my question is with regards to AVCam sample code by Apple where they observe few states as follows. This is done in CameraModel class which is attached to SwiftUI view.
    // MARK: - Internal state observations

// Set up camera's state observations.
private func observeState() {
    Task {
        // Await new thumbnails that the media library generates when saving a file.
        for await thumbnail in mediaLibrary.thumbnails.compactMap({ $0 }) {
            self.thumbnail = thumbnail
        }
    }
    
    Task {
        // Await new capture activity values from the capture service.
        for await activity in await captureService.$captureActivity.values {
            if activity.willCapture {
                // Flash the screen to indicate capture is starting.
                flashScreen()
            } else {
                // Forward the activity to the UI.
                captureActivity = activity
            }
        }
    }
    
    Task {
        // Await updates to the capabilities that the capture service advertises.
        for await capabilities in await captureService.$captureCapabilities.values {
            isHDRVideoSupported = capabilities.isHDRSupported
            cameraState.isVideoHDRSupported = capabilities.isHDRSupported
        }
    }
    
    Task {
        // Await updates to a person's interaction with the Camera Control HUD.
        for await isShowingFullscreenControls in await captureService.$isShowingFullscreenControls.values {
            withAnimation {
                // Prefer showing a minimized UI when capture controls enter a fullscreen appearance.
                prefersMinimizedUI = isShowingFullscreenControls
            }
        }
    }
}

If we see the structure CaptureCapabilities, it is a small structure with two Bool members. These changes could have been directly observed by a SwiftUI view. I wonder if there is a specific advantage or reason to use AsyncStream here & continuously iterate over changes in a for loop.
   /// A structure that represents the capture capabilities of `CaptureService` in
  /// its current configuration.
struct CaptureCapabilities {

let isLivePhotoCaptureSupported: Bool
let isHDRSupported: Bool

init(isLivePhotoCaptureSupported: Bool = false,
     isHDRSupported: Bool = false) {
    self.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported = isLivePhotoCaptureSupported
    self.isHDRSupported = isHDRSupported
}

  static let unknown = CaptureCapabilities()
}


They aren’t interchangeable or even related for that matter. Observable is for UI and an AsyncStream is for everything

You can use withObservationTracking to execute a closure when an observable property changes.  It probably really depends on the situation. If you have an observable you are using in a view and also want to react to changes from a non-view class then it could be a valid approach. If you only need to publish a stream of changes into non-view classes then AsyncStream is probably a better approach

@Rob I edited the question with more details.

@Paulw11 I added more details to the question.

It isn't "continuously iterating over the changes". It is receiving the changes as they occur. As Rob said, you could probably make both ways work.  In general you want to minimise the logic that is in a view, so putting it in the model probably makes sense

In AVCam the model wouldn’t get those values without the stream. The model needs to get its values from someone to redraw the view. These concepts are not equivalent. OnChange needs a source for information that will redraw the body. AsymcStream is more a kin to a Combine source of truth.

@loremipsum You are right. CameraModel is an @Observable class which in turn stores CaptureService which is declared as an actor. This class(CaptureService) publishes lot of properties and some of these properties are observed in the above code. I have previously solved similar problems instead by nesting Observable objects. In this case, CaptureService could also have been an Observable but I see Swift actors can not be marked as Observable. May be that is why the code chose this architecture.

Observable is designed to work with SwiftUI/UI. Once you leave the presentation layer it is no longer appropriate. Nesting Observable or ObservableObjects is generally not considered to be optimal. Everything has an exception but tools built to work with SwiftUI’s redrawing are unnecessary outside a View.

I think your question is more in the View struct/MVVM debate vs an AsyncStream/Observable. Apple has a “model” for camera work because AVFoundation and AVKit are reference based. Reference types can be very leaky when using it in with the view/struct pattern.

@loremipsum yes I realise the question is actually view struct vs MVVM debate which is something pointed out by another user on reddit. But I am not aware of that debate.

@loremipsum Observable macro was designed to be make it possible nesting multiple observable objects and reference types. Why do you say  observable class should not contain reference types I wonder.

Observable was designed to replace ObservableObject. I didn’t say you shouldn’t nest reference types I said you shouldn’t nest ObservableObjects. As in a Manager/Service has no reason to have capabilities to update UI. Observable and ObservableObject is for updating UI. Google “SwiftUI and MVVM”, find articles where they say that SwiftUI shouldn’t use MVVM. There will be much more articulate people on the subject.

@mahal do you have any good view struct vs mvvm references?

Found this highly opinionated article on why not to use MVVM in SwiftUI

Architecture is always opinionated but the difference between using onChange/task with a State and using Observable boils down to architecture. View/struct is hands down the most performance friendly version but not recommended for something like AVCam because of AVFoundation’s and AVKit’s reference type objects.

A few questions here:

To answer the question in the abstract, AsyncSequence (of which AsyncStream is just one concrete example) is a more general pattern. When implemented correctly, supports cancelation, yields values asynchronously over time, and where needed, and it has the notion of “finishing” when the sequence is done. The ObservableObject/@Observable patterns are a more narrow pattern (notably, @Observable is ideally suited for SwiftUI, a little cumbersome in UIKit/AppKit) for publishing changes of some state of an object. For your specific example (for informing SwiftUI of state changes over time), both observation and asynchronous sequences can accomplish the job; I wouldn’t lose too much sleep regarding one over the other.

Observation-related patterns are quite natural when a UI wants to be updated based upon the state for an object. It is a little less natural when you want some object (such as this “camera” service) to update its state based upon other events (though you can do it). I see no inherent flaw in the asynchronous sequence pattern employed here. But you could adopt either pattern here. In fact, they are just creating asynchronous sequences from publishers using values, so it is a bit of a mix of both.

If you are going to use asynchronous sequences, we should note that all of the unstructured concurrency in this observeState is a questionable implementation. It is launching four unstructured tasks with no way to cancel them.
Sure, they are launching this from the AVCamApp, so in this case they aren’t contemplating ever stopping the CameraModel, but I would really discourage this pattern. One shouldn’t bake in non-cancellable behavior, especially in demo project that developers might be inclined to copy and/or incorporate in their projects.
One would generally save references to these tasks and then provide a stop/cancel function to cancel them. Or, in this case, better, lose the unstructured concurrency, wrap these four in a task group:
private func observeState() async {
    await withDiscardingTaskGroup { group in
        group.addTask { @MainActor [self] in
            for await thumbnail in mediaLibrary.thumbnails.compactMap({ $0 }) {
                …
            }
        }

        group.addTask { @MainActor [self] in
            for await activity in await captureService.$captureActivity.values {
                …
            }
        }

        group.addTask { @MainActor [self] in
            for await capabilities in await captureService.$captureCapabilities.values {
                …
            }
        }

        group.addTask { @MainActor [self] in
            for await isShowingFullscreenControls in await captureService.$isShowingFullscreenControls.values {
                …
            }
        }
    }
}

Then, we would change start (which I would rename run) to do this last:
func run() async {
    // Verify that the person authorizes the app to use device cameras and microphones.
    guard await captureService.isAuthorized else { … }
    do {
        await syncState()

        try await captureService.start(with: cameraState)
        status = .running
        await observeState() // do this last; when `run` is cancelled, this will automatically be cancelled, too
    } catch { … }
}

Then a View could do something like:
var body: some View {
    CameraView(camera: camera)
        .task {
            // Start the capture pipeline. If view is dismissed, asynchronous sequences will be cancelled.
            await camera.run()
        }
}

Now, again, the original code sample was doing this in the App, so this problem did not manifest itself there. But the above would be a more generalized solution, working both in an App and a View.
The original code’s use of all of this unstructured concurrency and the failure to contemplate cancellation is an anti-pattern. We want CameraModel to be able to be used either from an App or a View. (I will ignore whether CameraModel is a good name for this object or not; it feels like a “service” than a simple “model”, IMHO.)



Thanks for answering. Couple of doubts as I learn about new things in Swift concurrency, you are using withDiscardingTaskGroup and then saying it is possible to cancel the task group. It doesn't look like it is possible from the documentation of withDiscardingTaskGroup

Ok I see your comment in code // do this last; when \run` is cancelled, this will automatically be cancelled, too`

I am wondering why you are doing await withDiscardingTaskGroup, which means you are waiting for all the tasks in the group to finish. So the run function will never return unless cancelled. If one needs to stop and run the camera again for any reason, it seems impossible.

@DeepakSharma – Let us continue this discussion in chat.
